# simulate enter keypress after a command is executed

Tags: linux, shell, expect, spawn

I am doing SSH to a host and executing a command and the command asks you to press the enter key. (It asks twice for different things.)

I am using spawn expect here.

When you send the report command, it will ask for you to press ENTER key. Once that is done, again it asks you to press enter. I want to send the enter key automatically.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@host report
expect "Press ENTER to continue, or CTRL-C to quit."
send " \r"
expect "Press enter for inputing"
send "\r"
```

ENTER should be done automatically and get the end result of the command.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: You have a space before the `\r` in the first `send`: `send "<SPC>\r"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say you have the "report" script on machine "audrey":

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Press ENTER to continue, or CTRL-C to quit."
read
echo -n "Press enter for inputing"
read
read s
echo "You sent: $s"
```

and the local expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh audrey ./report
expect "Press ENTER to continue, or CTRL-C to quit."
send "\n"
expect "Press enter for inputing"
send "\n"
send "OK\n"                                                                           
expect "You sent: OK"
close
```

./a.expect output:

```
spawn ssh audrey ./report
Press ENTER to continue, or CTRL-C to quit.
Press enter for inputing
OK
You sent: OK
```